# Generate all combinations of the SUM in Ruby but only using specific amount of numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I am currently pulling in F1 prices from an Api, placing them into an Array. and determining what combination is less than or equal to 20. Using the below successfully:

```
    require 'net/http'
    require 'json'
    @url = 'HIDDEN URL AS HAS NO RELEVANCE'
    @uri = URI(@url)
    @response = Net::HTTP.get(@uri)
    @fantasy = JSON.parse(@response)

    arr= [[@fantasy.first["Mercedes"].to_f, @fantasy.first["Ferrari"].to_f], [@fantasy.first["Hamilton"].to_f, @fantasy.first["Verstappen"].to_f]]
    target = 20
    @array = arr[0].product(*arr[1..-1]).select { |a| a.reduce(:+) <= target }
```

Where:

```
@fantasy = [{"Mercedes" => "4", "Ferrari" => "6.2", "Hamilton" => "7.1", "Verstappen" => "3"}]
```

This is successfully outputting:
`[[4.0, 7.1], [4.0, 3.0], [6.2, 7.1], [6.2, 3.0]]`

Eventually this will contain all F1 teams on the left side and all F1 drivers on the right (making an F1 fantasy teambuilder). But the idea is that only 1 constructor is needed and 5 drivers for the combination that should be equal or less than 20.

Is there a way to define this? To only use 1 Team (Mercedes, Ferrari etc) and 5 drivers (Hamilton, Verstappen etc) in the calculation? Obviously do not have 5 drivers included yet as just testing. So that my output would be:

`[[4.0, 7.1, 3.0], [6.2, 7.1, 3.0]]`

Where the constructor forms the 'base' for the calculation and then it can have any 5 of the driver calls?

My final question is, considering what I am trying to do, is this the best way to put my API into an array? As in to manually place `@fantasy.first["Mercedes"].to_f` inside my array brackets?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code as text please, not as an image.

Comment: BTW, since you got the API part working, you could leave that out and start your example / question with the `@fantasy` array right-away. Providing explicit input / example data would also help us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: By "explicit input" I meant something like `@fantasy = [{"Name" => "4", "ID" => "6.2", "Points" => "7.1"}, ...]` (replace with actual data). Just imagine me copying your code and trying to run it. Right now, I'd get an error because `@response` is undefined / `nil`. Also, what is your expected result for that given input? How should your output array look like?

Comment: @Stefan In this case I've left the API data in as the second part of my questions involves understanding if this is the proper way to turn API into Array

Comment: _"how many numbers to use in the left bracket and then how many to use in the right one"_ – what do you mean? What's your expected result?

Comment: @Stefan thanks have restructured my question :)

Comment: How do we know what keys are "drivers" and what keys are "constructors" (would recommend rephrasing to "manufacturer")? Also the URL you have posted does not represent the data in the question please consider revising or providing a sample of the data you are actually retrieving.

Comment: @engineersmnky I've rephrased but thought it was quite obvious. I had to include the URL based on the suggestions above, but now removed it as it has no relevance. And what's on the URL doesn't change the answer to the question. I've provided a sample of data in the question  - thanks

Comment: You still did not answer the first question. How do I know "Mercedes" and "Ferrari" are constructors and "Hamilton" and "Verstappen" are drivers? What if the key was "Ford", how would I determine if this was a driver or a constructor?

Comment: I concur with all the comments above. You are asking two unrelated questions so you should post two questions. One reason for doing that is that you will get much better answers to both. I, for one, do not understand your first question. If you were more disciplined when taking the place of a reader in your mind's eye you would come to the same conclusion. Incidentally, the reason for not posting pictures of code (or data) is twofold: it prevents users from cutting and pasting your code, and links have a habit of being broken in future.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, but does this help?

```
arr = @fantasy.first.values.map(&:to_f)
target = 20
p result = arr.combination(2).select{|combi| combi.sum <= target}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Not quite what I'm wanting. Guessing no one understands my explanation.  It's for a game where you're only allowed to pick 1 constructor and 5 drivers to build the best team. But there are 10 constructors to choose from and 20 drivers. So I was looking for all the combinations where 1 constructor + 5 drivers is = to or less then 20 - which is why I thought the best approach was to put constructors all in one array and drivers all in another. But couldn't then work out how to specify the number of values to use from each side. Does that make sense?